# how to write if null surround-with code snippet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I'm trying to write a vs code snippet that will take the selected and surround it with an if null check, i.e.

```
accgrp.CREATEDATE = DateTime.Now;
```

will become:

```
if (accgrp.CREATEDATE == null)
        {
            accgrp.CREATEDATE = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

I've got as far as the below. $selected$ only seems to work the last time it is used, if used more than once, the other instances where you would expected to see the selected code are blank. I understand the code below wouldn't do exactly what I want, as I wont get the right hand side of the assignment, btu it would be good enough.

```
            <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>expression</ID>
                <ToolTip>Expression to evaluate</ToolTip>
                <Default>o</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[if ($selected$ == null)
{
    $selected$ = $expression$$end$   
}]]>
        </Code>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is macro for you, that will provide you identical functionality.

```
Sub NullCheck()
    Dim selected As String
    Dim var As String
    Dim res As String
    Dim sel As TextSelection


    sel = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    selected = sel.Text        
    var = selected.Substring(0, selected.IndexOf("=") - 1).Trim()
    res = String.Format("if ({0} == null) {1} ", var, selected)

    sel.Delete()
    sel.Insert(res, vsInsertFlags.vsInsertFlagsContainNewText)
    sel.SmartFormat()

End Sub
```

The alternative (after reading your comment) may be to use [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) in order to intercept field/property setter.

Comment: v. nice - I've never used the macros before. I added a WrapInBrackets function to get past the stylecop:

Function WrapInBrackets(ByVal var, ByVal selected)

        Dim res As String

        res = String.Format("if ({0} == null)", var)
        res = res & vbCrLf & "{"
        res = res & vbCrLf & selected
        res = res & vbCrLf & "}"

        WrapInBrackets = res

    End Function

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `CREATEDATE` is a property, why don't you move this logic over there?

```
DateTime? CREATEDATE
{
    set { _createdate = value ?? DateTime.Now; }
}
```

or use the same `??` operator outside setter:

```
accgrp.CREATEDATE = accgrp.CREATEDATE ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: nice approach, i'd forgotten about the ?? operator. however i can't move the logic to the setter as accgrp is an entity in the entity framework. for every property on the entity i need to set a default where the user has entered no value. i understand that there's a defaultvalue property in the ef designer, but it can't take functions. your second suggestion is cool, but still suffers from not being able to use $selected$ twice in a snippet